# Plastic most closely mimicking Ultem in Autodesk Inventor

Tags: material, cad, analysis

I'm trying to run a stress analysis on an assembly of parts that will be printed in Ultem 9085 (on a Fortus 400MC). I am trying to find a **plastic that most closely mimics the material properties of Ultem in the Inventor materials library**. SOLIDWORKS had PEI which was near perfect, and I see that there's a thermoplastic resin in that library, but I can't seem to find PEI in Inventor. I was wondering if that thermoplastic resin is the best option, or if anyone knows another material in the Inventory library that would be more applicable. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find any. 3D printed parts are non-isotropic due to the layers. I'm pretty sure any simulation will assume the plastic is isotropic.